# How to split large json fetch in react

Tags: json, reactjs, performance, fetch

Have a question about best practise of fetching large json data from reactjs application.

Let's say we have fetch url foo.com and we also have from,to variables like 0 to 6 or whatever we put there. And we have about 10 000 elements in response json.

I need all these rows because I need to make sorting about all of them. But it takes too much time rendering them all together.

Is there any good practise.

1. Fetch them all and client waits (using at the moment)
2. Fetch n items until all fetched (better speed?)
3. Fetch n items, show already fetched data and fetch remaining values in background (In this case only sorting part waiting until last fetched, but client can look around already on page)

Comment: Standard response: Pagination. Fancier response: NDJSON streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching 10K items *at once* is not a good idea in most cases. Neither
is rendering 10K items on the screen. The trick is to find a sweet spot in UX that allows you to NOT render/fetch this many items.

You need to ask yourself what's the most important thing for user on this page.

- Do they want to see the top most *blah* record?
- Do they mostly care about seeing and eyeballing the items?
- Are they searching for a particular item?

If you can't change the api do the sorting for you on the server, then here is what I would do:

1. load first 100 items, sort them and then render them on the scree
2. kick of the fetch for the next 100 item and show a loading message to user
3. once the second page is fully fetched, sort all 200 and before rendering indicate on the UI that "there is new data, click here to see" but still only render the top 100 ones
4. repeat until you have all the items but give the user the ability to cancel at any time

The benefits are:

- √ user sees data as soon as first page is there
- √ you always render 100 items with a "show more" button so your DOM will be lean
- √ they can cancel at any time if they have found what they were looking for